# Need help understanding syntax found in the arrow function a.find( c=>!( a[-c]^=1 ) )

Tags: javascript

trying to attempt learn more about the new javascript syntax and came across this.

```
a.find(c=>!(a[-c]^=1))
```

I would very much appreciate it if someone could expand this out and explain the syntax for me.

For more clarity.

the array is a set of integers. The goal is to find the first duplicate in the set.

ie. if a = [1,2,4,5,4,1]

the function should return 4

`a.find(c=>!(a[-c]^=1))`

the above is the part of the function which finds first duplicate.

1. specifically what i don't understand is how -c which is negative of the value in the set is helping not return undefined all the time since there is never a negative index in the array.
2. a[-c]^=1 is some for of comparison that i'm not familiar with so an example of it's concept or a link to docs would be much appreciated.
3. why is it evaluated with 1
   Thank You.

Comment: Depends on what `a` contains. What specifically don’t you understand? Have you checked the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)? Also see [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `!` is the [Boolean not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)), `a[...]` accesses a property on `a`, where the property name is result of evalating `-c`. `-` is the [unary negation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation_(-)). `x ^= y` is the same as `x = x ^ y`. `^` is the [bitwise XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR)).

Comment: I can guess that a is definitely array of negative numbers as then only it can give positive indices.

Comment: ok sorry i didn't think the array contents matter i'll add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.find()
```

`a` is an Array and `Array.prototype.find` is looking for the first element that returns `true` or if no element has been found `undefined`.

Let's take a look into the arrow function.

```
c=>!(a[-c]^=1)
```

`c` represents an element in `a` and `a[-c]` references the entry with the index of negative `c`, further called `b`. `!(b^=1)` assigns `b` the result of  the [bitwise XOR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_XOR_assignment) `b^=1` or transformed `b=b^1`. The new value of `b` gets returned and every negated integer besides `0` returns `false`.

Comment: The last part is not quite right: `b^=1` is equal to `b = b ^ 1` which yields the XOR of `b` and `1`([XOR assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_XOR_assignment_2)). It's not a comparison to `1`. Also `!` converts to boolean, i.e. `false` for negative numbers and `true` for positive (including zero).

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. The only questions i have left is why isn't the negative `c` not returning `undefined` all the time if the array doesn't have negative indexes.

Comment: @FK82 I actually don't understand the difference. Could you provide me with more details?

Comment: @chr `b^=1` is an **assigment** operation, it assigns `b` the value of `b^1`. What you said would have to be written `b^1 === 1`. `!` isn't returning the negated value of `b^=1` since this is a number. For numbers `!` is boolean conversion. My first comment was wrong about the return value though: it's `true` for `0` and `false` for everything else.

Comment: @PierreSmith You can actually use negative integers for indexing as well. They are being silently converted to strings: for example, let `const o = {'-1': 'a'};` then you can retrieve the value with the index `-1` and `o[-1] === 'a'` will return `true`.

Comment: @FK82 thank you for your comment, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @FK82 you are right, I was mistaken and deleted my comment. Assignments are returning the assigned value :).

Answer (score 0):

To understand, whats happen, you need to understand that an array is a special form of an object with some special feature.

In this case the array is (mis)used as storage for a temporary result of a flag, which is changed like a flip-flop with a bitwise XOR.

To see, what is in the array, you need to convert the array to an object. The content is the final value after returning from find.

The reason for taking negative indices is to keep the original values at the given indices.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 1]

console.log(a.find(c => !(a[-c] ^= 1)))

console.log(Object.assign({}, a));
```